# Android Support Library is not recognized

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with the Android Support Library. I've downloaded and it shows up in my SDK (under Extras). However, when I try to import `android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader` to an Activity it gives an error:

> The import android.support cannot be resolved

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: WarrenFaith - which answer of yours have I not accepted?

Comment: OK, I thought clicking that the answer was helpful was the way to do this. I'll go back to my questions and accept the answers if I can figure out how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the support library jar file and place it in your projects "libs" folder for it to be detected. The jar file you need is located in your SDK folder under \extras\android\support\v4 and is called "android-support-v4.jar"

Comment: Are we talking about the files under C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk? I have a folder called extras there, but under it there's no android folder

Comment: Yes that is where I'm talking about. If the support library shows as installed under the SDK manager it should be in there.

Comment: OK, and which libs folder? I see two: one under platform-tools and one under tools. I do not see one under my project folder. Thanks!

Comment: if there is not one under your project folder simply create one :) It goes in YourProject/libs .. Put the support jar there .. refresh your project in eclipse.. blammo! support library!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can also make a right click on your project > Android tools > Add support library

Comment: That's what I initially did, Damien, but I get the error message I described above.

Comment: This worked for me. Interestingly enough even though I updated the support library via SDK manager this was not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Project properties_> java build path -> add external jars

.......\sdk_v13\extras\android\compatibility\v13

Worked for me and there are earlier versions of the support library there too.